# Is it possible to add an attribute to HtmlTextWriter WriteBreak

Tags: c#, htmltextwriter

Is it possible to add a class to a br tag when using the HtmlTextWriter.WriteBreak method?

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "className");
writer.WriteBreak();
```

I need an xHtml compliant html output and therefore the WriteBreak is perfect as it writes

```
<br />
```

I want to add a class to the br so that I have

```
<br class="className" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it manually, like this:

```
writer.WriteBeginTag("br");
writer.WriteAttribute("class", "className");
writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd);
```